# What is the implementation of `strtol`?

Tags: c

I'm just curious about this. `strtol` does not require you to specify the number of bytes to process, so in theory it may be fed a string containing an endless sequence of digits to consume, leading to a denial-of-service attack. Of course, it is easily thwarted by realizing that at once the precision of the long has been exhausted (couldn't really be more than 65 chars of a binary number) there is no point in reading any further.

However, `strtol` is also required to discard as many whitespace characters as necessary until the first non-whitespace character is encountered. So could it not be attacked with an endless whitespace string even if it is smart about reading digits?

Comment: Your "endless" string of whitespace would require endless memory. [Here](ftp://ftp.irisa.fr/pub/OpenBSD/src/sys/lib/libsa/strtol.c) is an example of an implementation. It is indeed smart about not reading too many digits.

Comment: You should verify the arguments you give to strtol - as you should with most library functions. e.g. the 1. argument have to be a string (i.e. it must be nul terminated). And if it concerns you, verify that you do not give it an infinite long string.

Comment: use `fgets()` (and `sscanf()`) to read user input!

Comment: You don't need `strtol` for a DOS attack if your application can be fooled into trying to consume an _endless stream of digits_.

Comment: @user786653 I like your comment better than any of the answers.

Comment: @user78: That example doesn't work when the base character set is EBCDIC!

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/strtol.c Here's the sourcefile of `strtol`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, strtol is also required to discard as many whitespace characters as necessary until the first non-whitespace character is encountered. So could it not be attacked with an endless whitespace string even if it is smart about reading digits?

As `strtol` works on a string already in memory you would have had to store (and read from an attacker) an "endless" amount of whitespace (or forgotten to NUL-terminate your string) before even feeding it to strtol.

Since an implementation can keep calculate the maximum number of digits there can ever be in a valid string it doesn't have to keep going, as you suspect.

DOS attacks can occur with faulty implementations though, check out [this](http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-hangs-when-converting-2-2250738585072012e-308/) related case (this was in java and PHP when reading doubles, but the same could occur in a C or C++ implementation).

Answer (score 2):

There is no single implementation of `strtol`.  I doubt that any implementation is susceptible to the kind of attack you describe; the obvious implementation would just traverse the sequence of digits without storing them all at once.  (Note that the digit sequence can be arbitrarily long due to leading `0`s.)

If you want to see the code for an implementation, you can download the glibc version [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/); `strtol()` is in `stdlib/strtol.c`.

Answer (score 0):

My personal implementation. I didn't use any lookahead (accessing `p[1]` or something like that), so theoretically you can convert this to something reading from a stream (e.g. `get_long()` that calls `getc()` for characters).

```
#include <errno.h>
#define LONG_MAX ((long)(~0UL>>1))
#define LONG_MIN (~LONG_MAX)
int isspace(int c); /* <-- Forward declare from <ctype.h> */ 

long strtol(const char *restrict nptr, char **restrict endptr, int base) {
    const char *p = nptr, *endp;
    _Bool is_neg = 0, overflow = 0;
    /* Need unsigned so (-LONG_MIN) can fit in these: */
    unsigned long n = 0UL, cutoff;
    int cutlim;
    if (base < 0 || base == 1 || base > 36) {
#ifdef EINVAL /* errno value defined by POSIX */
        errno = EINVAL;
#endif
        return 0L;
    }
    endp = nptr;
    while (isspace(*p))
        p++;
    if (*p == '+') {
        p++;
    } else if (*p == '-') {
        is_neg = 1, p++;
    }
    if (*p == '0') {
        p++;
        /* For strtol(" 0xZ", &endptr, 16), endptr should point to 'x';
         * pointing to ' ' or '0' is non-compliant.
         * (Many implementations do this wrong.) */
        endp = p;
        if (base == 16 && (*p == 'X' || *p == 'x')) {
            p++;
        } else if (base == 2 && (*p == 'B' || *p == 'b')) {
            /* C23 standard supports "0B" and "0b" prefixes. */
            p++;
        } else if (base == 0) {
            if (*p == 'X' || *p == 'x') {
                base = 16, p++;
            } else if (*p == 'B' || *p == 'b') {
                base = 2, p++;
            } else {
                base = 8;
            }
        }
    } else if (base == 0) {
        base = 10;
    }
    cutoff = (is_neg) ? -(LONG_MIN / base) : LONG_MAX / base;
    cutlim = (is_neg) ? -(LONG_MIN % base) : LONG_MAX % base;
    while (1) {
        int c;
        if (*p >= 'A')
            c = ((*p - 'A') & (~('a' ^ 'A'))) + 10;
        else if (*p <= '9')
            c = *p - '0';
        else
            break;
        if (c < 0 || c >= base) break;
        endp = ++p;
        if (overflow) {
            /* endptr should go forward and point to the non-digit character
             * (of the given base); required by ANSI standard. */
            if (endptr) continue;
            break;
        }
        if (n > cutoff || (n == cutoff && c > cutlim)) {
            overflow = 1; continue;
        }
        n = n * base + c;
    }
    if (endptr) *endptr = (char *)endp;
    if (overflow) {
        errno = ERANGE; return ((is_neg) ? LONG_MIN : LONG_MAX);
    }
    return (long)((is_neg) ? -n : n);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't  compile

Answer (score -1):

Well if you want to see the strtol you can see this by University  of California

```
/* 
 * strtol.c --
 *
 *  Source code for the "strtol" library procedure.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 1988 The Regents of the University of California.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, without written agreement and without
 * license or royalty fees, to use, copy, modify, and distribute this
 * software and its documentation for any purpose, provided that the
 * above copyright notice and the following two paragraphs appear in
 * all copies of this software.
 * 
 * IN NO EVENT SHALL THE UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA BE LIABLE TO ANY PARTY FOR
 * DIRECT, INDIRECT, SPECIAL, INCIDENTAL, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES ARISING OUT
 * OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE AND ITS DOCUMENTATION, EVEN IF THE UNIVERSITY OF
 * CALIFORNIA HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * THE UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS ANY WARRANTIES,
 * INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY
 * AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  THE SOFTWARE PROVIDED HEREUNDER IS
 * ON AN "AS IS" BASIS, AND THE UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA HAS NO OBLIGATION TO
 * PROVIDE MAINTENANCE, SUPPORT, UPDATES, ENHANCEMENTS, OR MODIFICATIONS.
 */
static const char rcsid[] = "$Header$ SPRITE (Berkeley)";

#include <ctype.h>

extern unsigned long int strtoul(char *string, char **endPtr, int base);

/*
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * strtol --
 *
 *  Convert an ASCII string into an integer.
 *
 * Results:
 *  The return value is the integer equivalent of string.  If endPtr
 *  is non-NULL, then *endPtr is filled in with the character
 *  after the last one that was part of the integer.  If string
 *  doesn't contain a valid integer value, then zero is returned
 *  and *endPtr is set to string.
 *
 * Side effects:
 *  None.
 *
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

long int
strtol(
    char *string,       /* String of ASCII digits, possibly
                 * preceded by white space.  For bases
                 * greater than 10, either lower- or
                 * upper-case digits may be used.
                 */
    char **endPtr,      /* Where to store address of terminating
                 * character, or NULL. */
    int base            /* Base for conversion.  Must be less
                 * than 37.  If 0, then the base is chosen
                 * from the leading characters of string:
                 * "0x" means hex, "0" means octal, anything
                 * else means decimal.
                 */
)
{
    register char *p;
    int result;

    /*
     * Skip any leading blanks.
     */
    p = string;
    while (isspace(*p)) {
    p += 1;
    }

    /*
     * Check for a sign.
     */
    if (*p == '-') {
    p += 1;
    result = -1*(strtoul(p, endPtr, base));
    } else {
    if (*p == '+') {
        p += 1;
    }
    result = strtoul(p, endPtr, base);
    }
    if ((result == 0) && (endPtr != 0) && (*endPtr == p)) {
    *endPtr = string;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This `strtol()` does not return `INT_MAX` nor `INT_MIN` on overflow as specified in the C spec.

Comment: Where's the source of `strtoul`?